# Mysql - condition column is equal to two or more value

Tags: mysql, sql

lately i've been working on an advanced search and his query builder. Now i'm facing a small

problem, lets say that in my search i want to include all the movie that have exactly genre_id 100 and 101 so basically i should get just the movie_id 10

```
 [Movie Table]
 movie_id  |title             |...
 10        |Bruce Almighty
 11        |Matrix

 [Movie Genres Table]
 movie_id | genre_id  |...
 10       |100
 11       |101
 10       |101
 ...      |...

 [movie Version Table]
 movie_id | version_id  |...
 10       |20
 10       |21
 11       |20
 10       |22

[movie language Table]
 movie_id | language_id  |...
 10       |30
 10       |40
 11       |11
 11       |14
```

and the query is the follow:

```
 SELECT movie_id,title from movie WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%'
```

i can't use HAVING because i have more field that can be exactly the same like versions(standard,extended,etc..)

Any Idea how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

i could go on for days adding table like this XD, are basically one to many relation table all with the same structure... and i have  to dinamically build the query (so that i'll just uinclude the needed condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an IN clause containing only movie IDs with only the two genres associated.

```
SELECT movie_id, title 
FROM movie 
WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%' 
AND movie_id IN
(
  SELECT movie_id
  FROM movie_genre
  GROUP BY movie_id
  HAVING MIN(genre_id) = 100 AND MAX(genre_id) = 101
);
```

EDIT: Here is about the same query only more versatile (you can have more values and they don't need to be adjacent):

```
SELECT movie_id, title 
FROM movie 
WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%' 
AND movie_id IN
(
  SELECT movie_id
  FROM movie_genre
  GROUP BY movie_id
  HAVING 
    MAX(CASE WHEN genre_id = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN genre_id = 101 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    MAX(CASE WHEN genre_id NOT IN (100,101) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
);
```

Comment: they can be not sequential, for lazyness i used 10,11 but could also be 3 and 108 ^^

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it made things easier with two adjacent values :-) However, it's not difficult to get the query more versatile. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do a join, checking the genre_id and do a count of the matching records.

```
SELECT movie.movie_id, movie.title 
from movie 
INNER JOIN Genres
ON movie.movie_id = Genres.movie_id
AND Genres.genre_id IN (10, 11)
WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%' 
GROUP BY movie.movie_id, movie.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

If there are other fields you need to return then you could you a sub query to identify the movie genre with the HAVING

```
SELECT movie.movie_id, movie.title 
from movie 
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT movie_id, COUNT(*) AS genre_count
    FROM Genres
    WHERE genre_id IN (10, 11)
    GROUP BY movie_id
    HAVING genre_count = 2
) sub1
ON movie.movie_id = sub1.movie_id
WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%'
```

EDIT - to check for a film which only has the genre 10 and 11 associated with it:-

```
SELECT movie.movie_id, movie.title 
FROM movie 
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT movie_id, COUNT(*) AS genre_count
    FROM Genres
    WHERE genre_id IN (10, 11)
    GROUP BY movie_id
    HAVING genre_count = 2
) sub1
ON movie.movie_id = sub1.movie_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT movie_id, COUNT(*) AS genre_count
    FROM Genres
    WHERE genre_id NOT IN (10, 11)
    GROUP BY movie_id
) sub2
ON movie.movie_id = sub2.movie_id
WHERE title LIKE '%Bruce%' 
AND sub2.movie_id IS NULL
```

Comment: that works, but i can't use having cause  genres is just one of the field that can be exactly 10,11 i could also want the movie with genres 10 and 11 , versions 20 and 21 and so on would become a nightmare to use having...

Comment: i'll try the second way to do it... i'll let you know :D

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail to the tables in your question please (for example what other columns you might want to check, and on which tables they are)

Comment: ok, i tried the second query, is almost perfect, the only problem is that "grab" also movie that have more than just 10 and 11 :( (like for example a movie that has 10,11,12 will be fetched anyway)

Comment: Ah, you only want movies that have genre 10 and 11 but no other genre associated with them. Let me have a think.

Comment: i was thinking,because i add the genre table anyway (for getting the name of the genres) i could add a count of the total there and then with php filter it

Comment: That would mean bringing the records back to php to process (likely to be slower that just doing it on the database). Also you presumably have one row per file per genre on the genres table hence the count would be repeated every line.